# Node.js event-stream: Where to setMaxListeners?

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventemitter, gulp, event-stream

I have searched and searched for this, to no avail. I've combed the web (including Stackoverflow), and the Node docs for an answer, and not found one---that worked (maybe that's just bad searching on my part). I'm working with an event-stream in a gulp config file, and I have a particular task that is hitting the classic "memory leak detected" error from the EventEmitter class. From what I've found, the answer to dealing with this issue seems to be to call the setMaxListeners method of the EventEmitter class; and my research has suggested that the event-stream has a Stream object, which should be an instance of EventEmitter. However, what ever way I try to call setMaxListeners, I get method not found. After exhausting myself researching the issue, I figured I'd bring it to the Node gurus here (I'm assuming this is simple, and I'm just missing something). Here's my code:

```
return eventStream.merge(
        gulp.src('./jscript/libs/file-one.js'),
        gulp.src('./jscript/libs/filder_one/file-two.js'),
        gulp.src('./jscript/libs/folder_two/file-three.js'),
        gulp.src('./jscript/libs/folder_three/file_four.js'),
        gulp.src('./jscript/libs/folder_four/file_five.js'),
        gulp.src('./jscript/libs/folder_five/file_six.js'), 
        gulp.src('./jscript/libs/file_seven.js'),
        gulp.src('./jscript/libs/file_eight.js'),
        gulp.src('./jscript/lists/rules/*.js')
    )        
    .pipe(concat('my_file.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./jscript/dist/'))
    .pipe(rename('my_file.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./jscript/dist/'));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but you can pass an array of glob patterns to 'gulp.src()' instead of merging multiple 'gulp.src()'s. Doesn't it solve your problem?

https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpsrcglobs-options

EDIT

As a direct answer, the following worked for me:

```
var merged = eventStream.merge(...);
merged.setMaxListeners(0);
return merged.pipe(...);
```

While event listeners are added in the merge function, the listener count seems to be checked between ticks of the event loop. So we can setMaxListeners right after adding listeners.

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem; however, yes, it was indirect, and I'm still really curious about how to actually set the EventEmitter.setMaxListeners on an event-stream---in case I might need it in some other circumstance (if anyone knows).

Comment: Added a direct answer.

Answer (score 3):

In Node.js 0.12 (soon to be released) you'll be able to set the max for all emitters:

```
var events = require('events');
events.EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners = 100;
```

More in the relevant [commit](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/cf0fa96db84caf9c1e6e5d0cb6f303cf6a8025c9).

Comment: Very helpful (I'll look forward to that release). Thanks.