# How to Call `setMaxListeners` when Combining NodeJS Streams

Tags: node.js, gulp, eventemitter

I'm using gulpjs to bundle sets of css files. Each set gets bundled into its own file, so my code looks something like:

```
var es = require('event-stream');

gulp.task("bundle", function(){
  var streams = [];
  for(var i in sets) {
    var set = sets[i];
    var stream = gulp.src(set.sources)
                     .pipe(...)
                     .pipe(gulp.dest(set.destination));
    streams.push(stream);
  }
  var merged = es.concat.apply(es, streams);
  return merged;
});
```

So it's been working fine, but now my bundles have gotten big enough that I see the following error:

> (node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.

I've tried to apply answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21716923/193896) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22381491/193896) but I can't seem to figure out where to call `setMaxListeners(0)`.

How do I call `setMaxListeners` when I'm merging streams?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the concern is with the `event-stream` module ([see this issue](https://github.com/dominictarr/event-stream/pull/53)).

For now, I was able to suppress the issue with this line of code. Of course, this sets the max globally which is not ideal.

```
require('events').EventEmitter.prototype._maxListeners = 30;
```

It appears that the issue will be eventually resolved in `stream-combiner` which is a dependency of `event-stream`.

Answer (score 1):

In [Node 0.12](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/cf0fa96db84caf9c1e6e5d0cb6f303cf6a8025c9#diff-47e194efdf163b1bffee1a62104a4588R71) you'll be able to set `EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners` for all instances.